# You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using this [MageREST](https://github.com/observo/MageREST) Framework in PHP for Magento 2.1.3 Installation.

But I am getting this error-

```
401 Unauthorized` response:
{"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."}
```

Comment: Make sure your credentials are correct, this error you will see only when you are unable to login. Rarely it happens because of account is suspended

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248820/mage-2-customer-token-error-for-some-accounts

Answer (score 3):

You Just Run this Command in Magento Root.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

It's Working after remove cache and generation folder..

Answer (score 2):

Create New User. Run this command in your magento root folder

```
sudo php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="ketan" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-email="ketan.borada9419@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="Ketan" --admin-lastname="Borada"
```

Comment: No its wrong..why you create another one?? you can unlock admin.

Comment: It's alternative method.When user not unlock

Answer (score 1):

**Change password by using below query in mysql**

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```