# Mage 2 Customer Token Error For Some Accounts

Tags: magento2, customer-account, rest-api, token

I have website with 5 customer test accounts. REST API calls have been working for a while now w/o a problem.

Today, one customer account cannot get the customer token via REST API call (API response 401: "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."), the other 4 accounts have no problems.

In the Mage 2 admin, zero accounts are locked. The account in question also shows as UNLOCKED in the account details. In the db > customer_entity table, the related account record has failure_nums = 0, lock_expires = null - same as all other accounts that work. We reset the password for the account, still the API does not authenticate this account.

Using the web front-end log in, the account does log in using the same email/pw used in the API call.

Any idea what is going on here with this one problematic account ?

This is a test environment, so not critical atm, but do not want to run into this in production.

Answer (score 2):

You're much likely to encounter a bug on core. A solution suggested by the user on github is clear the DB table `oauth_token_request_log`. You may have a try.

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4432#issuecomment-258114623

Comment: this solved the problem ! THANK YOU. Unfortunately cannot accept as answer because of my low reputation.

Comment: You can still upvote this:) And remember to accept my answer once you get enough rep.